# Select and deselect options in a select element based on a condition

Tags: jquery

i have about 1500 `select` list on a page which is having `option` A,B,C,D,E

My task is to find all `select` list having `option` **D** selected and deselect it and Select **E** instead of that. I don't have any `class` on select list & each select list is having a unique name and `id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `:selected` selector along with `attribute equals` selector to accomplish your task,

```
$('select option:selected[value=D]').parent().val('E');
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qPfuk/)

---

or you can use `:has()` selector to simplify the job

```
 $('select:has(option:selected[value=D])').val('E');
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qPfuk/1/)

Comment: @Deepesh Glad to help.! If you feel this answer has satisfied your need, then try to click on the tick mark available with this answer in order to show your acceptance to the future visitors.. And it is not a compulsion... :)